# How to search places in react-native-maps?

Tags: react-native-maps

I am using react-native-maps, and I want to find/search places if a user is searching through text tag?
Is it any way to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

here you can change your latitude & longitude coordinates using

**> Reverse Geo coding**

```
<MapView
    initialRegion={{
      latitude: this.state.latitude,
      longitude: this.state.longitude,
      latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
      longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
    }}
  />
```